# Is the vertex of an equation included in the increasing and decreasing intervals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the vertex of an equation included in the increasing and decreasing intervals of the function? For examples, I have function $f(x) = |x-2|+1$. Would the decreasing and increasing intervals be written as $(-\infty,2]$ and $[2,\infty)$? Or would they be written as $(-\infty,2)$ and $(2,-\infty)$. Thanks

Comment: Check what happens to the function at $x= 2$ and decide whether it must be included or excluded? Also, it depends on whether you need strictly increasing/decreasing intervals or just increasing/decreasing.

Comment: looking at the definition of [increasing or decreasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), I would say the function is decreasing on the interval $(-\infty,2]$ and increasing on $[2,\infty)$; by the way, $|x-2|+1$ is an expression, not an equation

Comment: Please, use correct mathematical terminology 1) "equation" refers to a mathematical expression with an equal sign somewhere ("$|x-2|+1$" is not an equation, "$y=|x-2|+1$" is an equation) 2) It's not an equation that has a vertex, it's its graphical represention that has one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x - 2| + 1$ is shown below.

[image: graph_of_shifted_absolute_value_function]

We note that its range is $[1, \infty)$ and that the minimum value of $1$ occurs when $x = 2$ since the expression $|x - 2| + 1 > |2 - 2| + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's consider the definitions of increasing and decreasing.

**Definition.**  A function $f$ is said to be *increasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$.  A function $f$ is said to be *strictly increasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

If $x \geq 2$, then $|x - 2| = x - 2 \geq 0$, so
$$f(x) = |x - 2| + 1 = x - 2 + 1 = x - 1$$
which is strictly increasing on $[2, \infty)$ since whenever $2 \leq x_1 < x_2$, $2 - 1 \leq x_1 - 1 < x_2 - 1$.  In particular, if $x > 2$, then $f(2) = 2 - 1 = 1 < x - 1 = f(x)$.

**Definition.**  A function $f$ is said to be *decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$.  A function $f$ is said to be *strictly decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

If $x \leq 2$, then $|x - 2| = -(x - 2) = -x + 2 \geq 0$, so
$$f(x) = |x - 2| + 1 = -x + 2 + 1 = -x + 3$$
which is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty, 2]$ since whenever $x_1 < x_2 \leq 2$, $-x_1 + 3 > -x_2 + 3 > -2 + 3$.  In particular, if $x < -2$, then $f(x) = -x + 3 > 1 = -2 + 3 = f(2)$.

Note that it is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the graph of the function that is included in the intervals where the function is increasing or decreasing, not the vertex.  As Jean Marie pointed out in the comments, the vertex is of the graph of the equation $y = |x - 2| + 1$, not the equation itself.

You are using interval notation incorrectly.  Let's look at definitions.
\begin{align*}
(a, b) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b\}\\
[a, b] & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \leq x \leq b\}\\
[a, b) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \leq x < b\}\\
(a, b] & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x \leq b\}\\
(a, \infty) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x > a\}\\
[a, \infty) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq a\}\\
(-\infty, b) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < b\}\\
(-\infty, b] & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq b\}
\end{align*}
Thus, $(-\infty, 2) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < 2\}$, while $(2, -\infty) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 2 < x < -\infty\} = \emptyset$.  The smaller number must be written first, otherwise the interval is empty.

Comment: OP wrote $[2,\infty),$ not $[2,-\infty)$, so perhaps $(2,-\infty)$ was merely a typo.